# How to use tar.gz in custom code and resource file option in Install4j

Tags: install4j

In archives section of Install4js custom code and resource option there are two options,which are jar and zip.
How can i use tar.gz file as i am working on Linux platform?

Basically i have bunch of static html files and css,js files which i need to open in browser using button click event through installet screens how can i do that?

By using tar.gz file i can extract that at target location and use the extracted file path to open in browser.
I can't use separate resource files  as my html and css,js files have directories and subdirectories.

Is there is any way to handle this more elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a tar.gz like "my.tar.gz" file on the "Installer->Custom Code & Resources" step and use a "Extract a TAR file" action with its "Tar file" property set to `${installer:sys.resourceDir}/my.tar.gz` and its "Destination directory" property set to `${installer:sys.resourceDir}`.